# What should be the size of my SVG file for using as html header background?

Tags: html, css, adobe-illustrator

i am using a 1336 x 768 pixel SVG file from illustrator but whenever i am using it as header background this image is not showing fully in bottom. Browser window hiding some bottom part of that image.

this is my CSS code

```
header{
       background-image: url(../contents/SVG/backg.svg);
       height: 100vh;
       background-size: cover;
       background-position: center;
    }
```

actual image in illustrator. Size 1336 x 736 px
[image: actual image]

but i am getting this in my browser view
[image: browser view]

Have i need to change in illustrator size or CSS file ?

Comment: you have to change the svg viewbox?

Comment: The issue is likely the height you have set. However, it would be nice if you produced more than just some CSS. We can't reproduce your problem in order to assist otherwise.